# Can't get the updated value from the textbox

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I'm loading table structure format in a page where one of the column is editable textbox where I fill the value in the Textbox from DB and User also update the value on the same. How to get the updated value from the textbox onclick of the submit button?

```
<FORM METHOD=POST>
<%
Dim hours2

DO WHILE Not objRSLabourT.EOF

hours2 = objRSLabourT("hours_2") 
Response.Write "<TD align='left'><input type='text' size='1' id='" & objRSLabourT("id") & "'  name='RnAh_" & objRSLabourT("id") & "'  value ='" & hours2 & "'></TD>" 

######

LOOP
%>
</FORM>

I tried the following in the place of ######

hours2 = Request.Form(id)
hours2 = Request.Form("" & objRSLabourT("id") & "")  
hours2 = Request("'" & objRSLabourT("id") & "'")
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The input fields are named `RnAh_xxxx`, so read them as `Request.Form("RnAh_" & xxxx)` where xxxx is the `objRSLabourT("id")` .

Comment: You could use your browser dev tools or a tool like Fiddler to check what the body content looks like in the request when you submit the form. This will tell you what the key to use is in Request.Form().

Comment: Thanks @Flakes both your comments helped me to fix the problem.  hours2 = Request("RnAh_" & objRSLabourT("id") )